# Convert date format qlikview

Tags: qlikview

My date is in the form of 31/01/2017. I want to format it as 31-Jan. How do I do it?

This doesn't work. There is an error.

```
=date(date#(=maxstring({[Date1]} [DATE]),'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MMM')
```

Comment: Hey can you post an example csv and tell what you are trying to achieve with "maxstring({[Date1]} [DATE]"?

Comment: What is the error? may be you are not passing the date properly

Answer (score 2):

Function `Date#()` returns the expression as a date according to the string given as format-code. If the format code is omitted, the `default date format` set in the operating system is used.

**Syntax:-**

```
Date# (text [, format])
```

After that use Date function to convert it to date. Let's look at below example:-

**Example:-**

```
=Date(Date#('16JAN2014','DDMMMYYY'))
```

Above we have converted character format of date to date using date# and date functions.

**Your Example:**

I am confused what are you doing here. Just check `(=maxstring({[Date1]} [DATE]),'DD/MM/YYYY')` and check is Date1 matching 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

And put it your date conversion format.

```
=date(date#( (=maxstring({[Date1]} [DATE]),'DD/MM/YYYY') , 'DD-MMM'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your source data too.
If the data format in the source is a date, then it will be read by QlikView as a date and the conversion is simple.

**Solution:** date(Date, 'DD-MMM') as Date

If the data format in the source is NOT a date format, but text, then you need to split the text string in pieces and tell for each section what it is, using the subfield() function. You enclose this with a date#() function, telling that these pieces of text have to be interpreted as a date. Finally you perform a simple date formatting function date() on this to get it in the DD-MMM format.

**Solution:** date(date#(subfield(Date,'/',1)&subfield(Date,'/',2)&subfield(Date,'/',3),'DDMMYYYY'),'DD-MMM') as Date

If it is important that your month is capitalized, you may want to check your initial SET statement in the script specifying the MonthNames:

SET MonthNames='jan;feb;mrt;apr;mei;jun;jul;aug;sep;okt;nov;dec';